# Comparing objects avoiding dynamic cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I've got the following classes:

```
class Father {
//some code
}

class child1: public Father {
//some code
}

class childN: public Father {
//some code
}
```

I've got two list of Father references. I need to check if one instance of a list is present in the other list. I need to do a "deep" check (not a pointer comparison). I can do it doing a `dynamic_cast` and then comparing the objects, but I'm wondering if there is some smart approach or pattern.

Edit: The Father class is a generic class and an unique identifier can be of some meaning only for some child classes.

Comment: Give them a unique id (e.g. a name), then you only have to compare this

Comment: Do you need to check if an *instance* of the object is in the list? Or an object which logically evaluates to equivalent?

Comment: +tobl303 Yep, I need to update my question but I'd like to avoid id in the father class because an id can be "meaning" only in child1 for example

Comment: btw are you sure about your classes? Any child is a father??

Comment: @NeilKirk I need a *logical* comparison.

Comment: Is `typeid` an option, or are you trying to avoid rtti?

Comment: You may look at [Double_dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Comment: +imreal I'd like to avoid rtti

Comment: `dynamic_cast` _is_ the smart approach, trying to create your own version of that with IDs in types will generally be inferior. The general problem is known as [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B)

Comment: @JonathanWakely The multiple dispatch seems the right way or at least is the right "pattern". Thanks.

Comment: The problem with `dynamic_cast` is performance, and the fact that if you do `dynamic_cast<Father*>(obj)` and the runtime type is `childX` you will get a cast, so you have to go bottom-up on the hierarchy. On the other hand `typeid` is harmless.

Comment: @imreal Father is abstract

Comment: What about adding something like `virtual std::string hash()` and comparing hashes?

Comment: @Kane It can be a good Java-style approach :)

Comment: @imreal, performance can be slow for complex hierarchies. In this case, not so much. I don't understand the rest of your comment. what is the static type of `obj` in your example? What does going bottom-up in the hierarchy mean? If `Father` is the base of the whole hierarchy why would you ever `dynamic_cast<Father*>` unless you have `void*`, which is not a problem in this case?

Comment: @JonathanWakely You're right about performance but I don't like to make assumptions about how big a hierarchy can become. Same thing for the other part of the comment, the hierarchy can grow to have multiple levels and could lead to incorrectly dispatching the method to the parent's implementation. So you have to go bottom-up (possibly in an `if...else` chain), i.e. tesing `dynamic_cast<Child*>` before `dynamic_cast<Parent*>`.